# std::shared_ptr<>型を基底クラスを派生クラスにダウンキャストできない原因が知りたい

Tags: c++

#### 質問内容

タイトル通りなのですが`std::shared_ptr<>` スマートポインタを用いて基底クラスを派生クラスにダウンキャストする方法が知りたいです。

#### 調べたこと

参考サイトより

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
std::shared_ptr<Base> base = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(derived);
```

を参考にDerivedがderでbaseがbaseに置き換わり派生から基底じゃなくて基底から継承になるだけなだけのはずなのですが以下のエラーが出ます。

#### エラー

```
$ make
g++ -c -MMD -MP src/Main.cpp -o obj/Main.o -I./../src -I ~/Library -I ~/Library/freetype 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:81,
                 from src/Main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = der; _Up = base]’:
src/Main.cpp:42:62:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:510:23: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘(& __r)->std::shared_ptr<base>::<anonymous>.std::__shared_ptr<base, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>::get()’ (of type ‘using element_type = std::remove_extent<base>::type*’ {aka ‘class base*’}) to type ‘using element_type = using element_type = std::remove_extent<der>::type*’ {aka ‘class der*’} (source type is not polymorphic)
  510 |       if (auto* __p = dynamic_cast<typename _Sp::element_type*>(__r.get()))
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:15: obj/Main.o] エラー 1
```

#### 調べたこと

`std::shared_ptr<der> b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<der>(d);`をコメントアウトするとエラーがなくなるのでこの下の行である最後の行がエラーの原因です。

#### 参考サイト

(shared_ptr の dynamic_cast 部): https://komorinfo.com/blog/cast-of-smart-pointers/#toc_id_2

#### 知りたいこと

スマートポインタstd::shared_ptr<>を用いて基底から派生にキャストする方法が知りたい

#### ソースコード(最下部)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class base
{
public:
    base()
    {
        std::cout<<"base() "<<std::endl;
    }
};

class der : public base
{
public:

    der() : base()
    {
        std::cout<<"der() "<<std::endl;
    }
};




int main()
{

    std::shared_ptr<base> d = std::make_shared<der>();
    std::shared_ptr<der> b = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<der>(d);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 直前のmake_sharedの行は変えず、`return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Sprite>(tex);`と変えるとどうなりますか？

Comment: 試したパターンはそれぞれエラーメッセージが異なりませんか？ 異なる場合は、質問文にそれぞれのエラーメッセージを載せるべきです。（質問者さんが取り上げた１例ではなく、正解に最も近いエラーメッセージで議論すべきだから）

Comment: 問題点に絞ったコードに修正しました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージに

> source type is not polymorphic

とあります。
つまり`base`クラスの派生クラスが多態的に振舞うために、`base`クラスに何らかの`virtual`関数が含まれている必要があります。
例えば `virtual ~base{}` などです。

なお、`std::shared_ptr`/`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`を使用せずとも、`dynamic_cast`でも同様の事が起きます。